# Ruby Newbie - Foreign Keys and Dropdowns on Forms

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails, and am struggling with foreign key relationships and pull down boxes on forms.  I have a Person table, with a foreign key to Jobtitle table.  Person has jobtitle_id, Jobtitle has pk id set in MySQL. In Person model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :jobtitle, :foreign_key => "jobtitle_id", :class_name => "Jobtitle"
  attr_accessible :id, :jobtitle
```

In JobTitle

```
class Jobtitle < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :jobtitle
  has_many :people
```

Controller:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_person, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :prepare_jobtitles

  ...
  private
    def prepare_jobtitles
      @jobtitles = Jobtitle.all
    end
```

In the edit form the dropdown is given by:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:jobtitle_id, @jobtitles, :id, :jobtitle) %>
```

In show.html.erb.

```
<p>
  <strong>Jobtitle:</strong>
  <%= select_tag 'jobtitle_id', options_for_select(Jobtitle.find_by_id(:jobtitle_id)) %>
```

The problems are:

(1) The edit form doesn't update the underlying table.  Is this because it is not passing the jobtitle_id back? or the foreign key constraint is failing when active record tries to update the record?

(2) I don't really want a `dropdown` box on the show page, just as text would be fine, but using `<%= @person.jobtitle %>` displays `# Jobtitle:0x4ea4dc0`

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Post your `attributes` of `Jobtitle` and `Person` models

Comment: Dont use `:jobtitle` as an `attribute` here.Rails treating it as `Jobtitle model instance`.Use title or name instaed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have given `jobtitle` as an attribute of `Jobtitle` model.Rails treating it as **`Jobtitle's model instance`** but not an **`attribute of Jobtitle`**.Try giving `title` or `name` instead as an attribute of `Jobtitle`.

In your `edit view`,the `drop-down` would be like this

```
<%= f.collection_select(:jobtitle_id, @jobtitles, :id, :title) %>
```

And in the show view,you can just give

```
<%= @person.jobtitle.title %>
```

to show the `associated jobtitle's title` of a `person`.

Currently you are giving `<%= @person.jobtitle %>` which is wrong

Comment: Thanks for that, makes total sense. So the show view is now correct, but it's still not updating the underlying table. The jobtitle_id field stays the same for every item in the Person table.

Comment: I literally have this line: <%= f.collection_select(:jobtitle_id, @jobtitles, :id, :name) %>

Comment: @thenapking Currently how many records you have in the jobtitles table?

Comment: This data is ported from a legacy database. There's just shy of 200 records in the jobtitle table. However I will be limiting it. Either way I can't hardcode the options for all my drop downs, they have to be setup as FKs.